# Assist with implementing cache on chat app

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, asyncstorage

I'm trying to save the messages from firebase to a cache then the flatlist will get the data from cache. I have a component called cache which has store and get function and it is working since I'm using it on a different screen to store data.

This is the function to get data from firebase

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {

        var unsubscribe;
        
        if (currentUser)
        {
            unsubscribe = db
            .collection("chats")
            .doc(currentUser.uid)
            .collection("messages")
            .orderBy("timestamp", "asc")
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {

                setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    message: doc.data().message,
                    timestamp: doc.data().timestamp.toDate(),
                    sender: doc.data().sender,
                    id: doc.id,
                })))
            });
        }
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [currentUser])
```

This is the function to store and get data from cache

```
const [cachedMessages, setCachedMessages] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
   async () => {
      await cache.store(cacheKeys.MESSAGES, messages);
    
      const data = await cache.get(cacheKeys.MESSAGES);
    
      setCachedMessages(data);
      }
   }, [messages])
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working?

Comment: Did you check if cache.store is every being called? It looks like you declare an anonymous lambda and never call it.

Comment: Nothing is displayed on the screen. I'm not able to see the cache though using React Native Debugger due to some error but I'm sure that the cache component is working.

Comment: If the problem is that nothing is being displayed, could you show us please how you are displaying your state? Also you might want to try `const fn = async() => {...}; fn()`

Comment: not calling the anonymous lambda is the problem lols. thanks! I don't really quite understand that lambda expressions